# How do I fix an Error from d3 presented in Cognos?

Tags: d3.js, cognos, cognos-11

I have a d3 visualisation used by a Cognos Analytics report, presented through an iFrame that is throwing an error at what appears to be random times.  The report is of live production data and is displayed for many hours in a factory. I am looking for advice about how to correct the problem.

The flow of data is from an ERP, to a Cognos list report. This list report is then referred to in a master .js file that then calls a d3.js file called "d3.v3.min.js".

In the master js file there is an statement that reads as follows:

```
error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
    //alert(errorThrown);
    alert("There was an error with the source data.  This is probably due to not being able to connect to the source Cognos report.  Please attempt to log in and try again.");
},
```

This error is then thrown at randomly when the report is displayed.

I had someone develop this solution for me and he is difficult to get hold of. This is now used in a production environment and although I know Cognos really well, I don't know js or d3 and am somewhat lost about how to stop the error occurring.

Any help or suggestions will be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I doubt the problem is in d3.v3.min.js.  In my experience with using d3 in custom controls in Cognos reports, it is probably a problem with the .js file that is associated with the custom control.  It is improperly handling unexpected values passed in through the Configuration property or the data set(s).  If the problem appears to be random, it probably has to do with the data.

Run the process in a test environment and track down the problem with the .js file.